# Simple Kivy app fails to buildoze

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I wrote a simple kivy app that replicates buttons

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ButtonApp(App):

    def add_button(self, none):
        button = Button(text='Press Me too!')
        button.bind(on_press=self.add_button)
        self.b.add_widget(button)

    def build(self):
        self.b = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(text="Press me!")
        button.bind(on_press=self.add_button)
        self.b.add_widget(button)
        return self.b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ButtonApp().run()
```

but when I run buildozer android debug, I get the following error

```
# Android SDK found at /Users/mmalkin/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
# Android NDK found at /Users/mmalkin/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Command failed: /Users/mmalkin/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/android list sdk -u -e
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
# and retry the latest command.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I've tried changing the directory to Macintosh HD, updating Java, and many other solutions suggested on this site. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2* try that

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not installed build-tools. Check this on-going bug report - https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/146

Summary of solution, run the Android SDK Manager and install that way.